# CATiledLayer PDF Performance is Poor on iPad 3 Retina Display

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, catiledlayer, retina-display

I'm using rather straightforward code to display a zoomable PDF in a scrollview, and it has been working beautifully on the iPad 2 and the original iPad. But it's staggeringly slow on the iPad 3. I know I'm pushing more pixels, but the rendering performance is simply unacceptable.

In iOS 5.0 and later, the tileSize property is arbitrarily clamped at 1024, which means tiles appear half that size on the retina display. Has anyone found a way to overcome this limitation?

Otherwise, has anyone found a way to improve the speed of the `CATiledLayer` on the iPad 3?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691891/catiledlayer-in-ipad-retina-simulator-yields-poor-performance

Comment: The question Mat pointed to has a workaround for your problem. Look at all the answers as there is a better workaround for your case available, than the one present in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, Mihai.  Unfortunately, that link doesn't have a workaround per se; only a few tweaks.  And those mostly are geared for the simulator and thus aren't of must interest for those of us developing for the device proper.  For instance, one tweak suggests lowering the contentScaleFactor to 0.5, which causes the layer to render at iPad 2 (non-retina) resolution.  Faster, yes, but not acceptable for a shipping product.

Comment: Two suggestions: can you create a tiny demo project and a representative pdf file and post it on Dropbox? Also, you might want to provide a bounty as an incentive to dig.

Comment: Did you remember to set the view's contentScaleFactor to 1 (or equivalently, the layer's contentScale?), ideally in -didMoveToWindow (after `[super didMoveToWindow]` sets it to whatever the current screen is)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `shouldRasterize` to `YES` on the layer?

Comment: Well, yes - rasterizing the layer of course improves performance.  But rasterization eliminates the benefit of tiled layers: the redrawing of tiles as the image is zoomed in.  Rasterized tiles look terrible at any zoom level greater than 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run a time profiler on these draws and did you rule out the possibility of redundant draws?

I've had some weird double drawing, which was easily found using:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    NSLog(@"draw %@", NSStringFromCGRect(CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(context)));
    // draw pdf
}
```

There's also a variety of settings to play with:

- `tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 2`
- `tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 4`
- `tiledLayer.tileSize = self.bounds.size`
- `CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationLow)`
- `CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault)`
- `self.contentScaleFactor = 1.0`